# Avoiding auto-adding a large dependency while building a node module. Is peerDependencies the only way?

Tags: javascript, npm

I am building an NPM module for modals. 
I want to use a heavy weight UI package named [material-ui](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui). Most of my projects already have it so I would like the package.json to follow this logic:

1. check if package already available
2. available? good - don't install it
3. not available? install it

I know that peerDependencies looks for existing packages which is good in the case my project has it. What happens if I put the package in dependencies? Does it always get installed or does it depends on whether it already exists? does it depend on versioning? are there any good options here? Clearly I would like to avoid complicated installation instructions like:

```
npm install modal-package
```

if your project doesn't have material-ui:

```
npm install material-ui@^0.17.1
```

Comment: npm moves dependencies on the same package up the tree when possible, yes. Don’t worry about it.

Comment: Is it documented? is it version related? if I specify ^0.17.1 and the user has 0.17.4, what happens? btw - I removed the code formatting I used for emphasis just for you! ;-)

Comment: Oh, your formatting is fine; code formatting is `this`, not **bold**. Anyway, yes, it’s version related. Packages can only share a dependency when the version specifications can both be satisfied. In your example, 0.17.4 will be used in both cases.

Comment: thx, it works. For some reason it doesn't do it for React and React-dom => so I'll just move them to peerDependencies

Comment: No, don’t move things to `peerDependencies` inappropriately. Are you running out of disk space? Try running `npm dedupe` instead.

Comment: Not disk space, bundle space. I use Webpack and my bundle becomes larger when I have more than one copy of a package. When react was in "dependencies" - it added a copy of it to each package that used it. I saw that material-ui are using peer dependencies for React. Could it be that react doesn't get moved up the tree by npm? https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/package.json

Comment: tnx, I ran npm dedupe and it's remarkable! Didn't know it exists. I wonder though, will my package users run it...

Comment: Newer versions of npm should dedupe as you’re installing, so particularly if you’re on an old version, I wouldn’t worry yet.